# manipulate portion of a function in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, replace, dom-manipulation

I'm looking for some solution to manipulate a part of HTML body scrip function by injecting some code using tampermonkey on every site load. The purpose of this workaround is to manipulate function behavior. Here's a simple example of what it's going to do:

```
<html>
<body>...</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function dosome() {
        ...
    };
    
    function startTimer() {
        var countDownTime = 1000 * 60;
        ...
        };
        
    </script>
</html>
```

For instance in code above, line `var countDownTime = 1000 * 60;` changes to `var countDownTime = 1000 * 45;`

Comment: Why don't you just make `startTimer` take a parameter called `seconds` and just pass `45` instead of `60`.

Comment: Note that by the time you have access to the contents of the `script` element, the JavaScript engine has already read it into memory, so changing the script won't do anything for you.

Comment: @HereticMonkey so what's your suggestion for doing this job?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It's an html code from a random website

Comment: You haven't explained what you're trying to do or why. The way one would solve the problem depends on what the final outcome should be.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt it by having the parameter be inputted through an input field. See code example below:

```
<html>
        <body>
            <input type="number" id="testInput" name="testInput" value="0">
            <button type="button" onclick="startTimer()">Submit</button>
            <p id="output">Output: </p>
        </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function startTimer() {
                var countDownTime = 1000 * document.getElementById("testInput").value;
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 'Output: ' + countDownTime;
            };
        </script>
    </html>
```

You could also make the call from within a button by using the OnClick event.